# Optionally descend a nested struct

Tags: c++, templates, nested

Assuming a class template `Optional` exists:

```
template <class T>
class Optional
{
public:
  ...
  bool isPresent(void) const {...}
  const T& value(void) {...} // throws if !isPresent()
  ...
};
```

Also, some structs with nested `Optional` fields are defined:

```
struct A;
struct B;
struct C;
struct D;

struct A
{
   Optional<B> b1_;
   int i_;
};

struct B
{
   Optional<C> c1_;
   int j_;
};

struct C
{
   Optional<D> d1_;
   int k_;
};

struct D
{
   int l_;
   int m_;
   int n_;
};
```

I'm looking for a programming idiom that provides the following behavior without the ugliness.

```
int get_l_OrDefault(const A& a, int def)
{
  if (!a.b_.isPresent()) return def;
  else if (!a.b_.value().c_.isPresent()) return def;
  else if (!a.b_.value().c_.value().d_.isPresent()) return def;
  else return a.b_.value().c_.value().d_.value().l_;
}
```

Given an `A a;`, can I define something that takes some representation of the path to the non-optional leaf field and a default value?

```
getValueOrDefault(a.b.j_, 0);
getValueOrDefault(a.b.c.k_, 0);
... etc
```

Comment: Uh, maybe `try {return a.b_.value().c_.value().d_.value().l_;} catch (...) {return def;}`?

Comment: In more functional languages, what you're asking for would be called a monad. I don't know of any monad libraries for C++, but that might give you a search term to start looking for.

Comment: I think this should be achievable using expression templates. You'd have to rely on operator-> since . is not overloadable, but it might be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
template <typename Class, typename Def, typename M>
Def getValueOrDefault(const Class& c, Def, M m)
{
    return c.*m;
}

template <typename Class, typename Def, typename  M, typename ... Ms>
Def getValueOrDefault(const Class& c, Def def, M m, Ms... ms)
{
    if (c.*m) {
        return getValueOrDefault(*(c.*m), def, ms...);
    } else {
        return def;
    }
}
```

With usage:

```
std::cout << getValueOrDefault(a, 0, &A::b, &B::j) << std::endl;
std::cout << getValueOrDefault(a, 0, &A::b, &B::c, &C::k) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/228b4723b5fe75ff)

Answer (score 0):

This needs bind.

Bind takes optional of a and a function from a to b or optional of b, and returns an optional of b.

Suppose we had a named operator `->*bind*` that understands poinnter to members.  Then

```
auto op_l = a->*bind*&A::b1_->*bind*&B::c1_->*bind*&C::d1_->*bind*&D::l_;
return value_or(op_l,def);
```

(Where value or takes an optional and a default).

Answer (score 0):

you need something recursive to do it. As an example, if you can have the same base class for your A, B, C, structs, you can have something like this:

```
struct Presentable <T> {
  Optional<T> opt;
  virtual int getIntValue(int def) {
    if (opt.isPresent())
     return opt.getValue().getIntValue(def);
    else
     return def;
    }
};

struct A : public Presentable<B>) {
  int i_;
};
...
struct D : Presentable <F> {
   int getIntValue(int) {return l_;}
}
```

Now you can get your value from the end of the chain or 'def'.

This is just one of possible variants, but in any case you would either need some base class, or you can use a pointer to create parent-child relation between structs (Optional class can help in doing so), or you can probably use dynamic cast for doing it.